# How to get from CouchDB only certain fields of certain documents for a single request?

Tags: couchdb

For example I have a thousands of documents with same structure, for example:

```
{
"key_1":"value_1",
"key_2":"value_2",
"key_3":"value_3",
...
...
}
```

And I need to get, let's say key_1, key_3 and key_23 from some set of documents with known IDs, for example, I need to process only 5 documents while my DB contains several thousands. Each time I have a different set of keys and document IDs. Is it possible to get that information for a one request?

Comment: Do you know the doc_id first hand ? Meaning you want to retrieve 5 documents from a list of doc_id and then extract the keys for each.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list function (see: [this](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html), [this](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#list-functions), and [this](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List#Listing_Views_with_CouchDB_0.10_and_later)).

Since you know the ids, you can then query `_all_docs` with the list function:

```
POST /{db}/_design/{ddoc}/_list/{func}/_all_docs?include_docs=true&columns=["key_1","key_2","key_3"]
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: {whatever}

{
  "keys": [
    "docid002",
    "docid005"
  ]
}
```

The list function needs to look at documents, and `send` the appropriate JSON for each one. Not tested:

```js
(function (head, req) {
    send('{"total_rows":' + head.total_rows + ',"offset":' + head.offset + ',"rows":[');

    var columns = JSON.parse(req.query.columns);
    var delim = '';

    var row;
    while (row = getRow()) {
        var doc = {};
        for (var k in columns) {
            doc[k] = row.doc[k];
        }
        row.doc = doc;
        send(delim + toJSON(row));
        delim = ',';
    }

    send(']}');
})
```

Whether this is a good idea, I'm not sure. If your documents are big, and bandwidth savings important, it might.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that’s possible. Your question can be broken up into two distinct problems:

1. Getting only a part of the document (in your example: key_1, key_3 and key_23). This can be done using a view. A view is saved into a design document. [See the wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Creating_Views) for more info on how to create views.
2. Retrieving only certain documents, which are defined by their ID. When querying views, you cannot only specify a single ID (or rather key), but also an array of keys, which is what you would need here. Again, see the [section on querying views](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options) in the wiki for explanations and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you only need a subset of values from a document, you may find that the system as a whole performs better if you just ask for the entire document then select the values you need from that result.

To only get the specific key value pairs you need to create a view that has view entries with a multipart key consisting of the doc id and doc item name, with value of the corresponding doc item.

So your map function would look something like:

```
function(doc){
    for(var i = 1; i < doc.keysInDoc; i++){
        var k = "key_"+i;
        emit([doc._id,  k], doc.[k]);
    }
}
```

You can then use multi key lookup with each key being of the form `["docid12345", "key_1"]`, `["docid56789", "key_23"]`, etc.

So a query like:

```
http://host:5984/db/_design/design/_view/view?&keys=[["docid002","key_8"],["docid005","key_7"]]
```

will return

```
{"total_rows":84,"offset":67,"rows":[
{"id":"docid002","key":["docid002","key_8"],"value":"value d2_k8"},
{"id":"docid005","key":["docid005","key_12"],"value":"value d5_k12"}
]}
```